# How to add data in an array inside object reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am building an react app and want to save multiple photos to firestore to do that i want to take their url in **imageurl: []** an array to save them in firestore.

```
      const [data, setData] = useState({

      name: "",
      phone: "",
      location: "",
      imageurl:[],

   })
```

here every data is saving and working fine name,phone,location but the problem is with **array value imageurl[]** they are not saving

i m saving urls like

```
            setData((prev)=> {

              return {

                ...prev, [data.imageurl] : [...data.imageurl , url]
              }
            })
           })
```

it is not working.

i am new to react please guide me how can i solve this problem. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `setData` when creating the return object you have put the value as key, when you set the key as `[data.imageurl]`. also don't use the data variable inside `setData`, use the `prev` variable supplied by the function

try this code

```
setData((prev) => {
   return {
      ...prev,
      imageurl: [...prev.imageurl, url],
  };
});
```

Comment: thank you so much brother. it means a lot

Comment: You're welcome..

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
  name: "",
  phone: "",
  location: "",
  imageurl: [],
});

// Function to add a URL to the imageurl array
const addImageUrl = (url) => {
  setData((prevData) => ({
    ...prevData,
    imageurl: [...prevData.imageurl, url],
  }));
};

// Example usage
const handleImageUpload = (url) => {
  // Assuming you have obtained the URL from somewhere
  addImageUrl(url);
};
```

You can then call `addImageUrl(url)` whenever you want to add a URL to the `imageurl` array. For example, you might call it inside an event handler that handles image uploads.

Comment: i have upvoted the answer brother

Answer (score 1):

You can tried like this also:

```
    setData((prevState) => ({
  ...prevState,
  imageurl: [...prevState.imageurl, url]
}));
```

The code updates the **imageurl** property in the component's state by creating a new state object that's a copy of the previous state and appends a new URL to the **imageurl** array.